# piped node.js ServerResponse object throws write after end in formidable event

Tags: node.js, stream, formidable

A basic html form with enctype='multipart' not included here. The first trip to the server serves without error, but after two trips through upload path. Node throws "write after end Error". 
 
 Calling resp.end() inside the event does not produce this error and it happens only if the stream piping is done inside of formidable event.

```
const http = require( "http" );
const form = require( 'formidable' ).IncomingForm();

    function fileStream( filepath){
        let readstream = fs.createReadStream(filepath );
        readstream.setEncoding( "utf8" );
        return readstream;
    }

    let server = http.createServer();
    server.listen( 8080 );

    server.on( "request", function( req, resp ){

        let requestpath = url.parse( req.url ).pathname.slice( 1 );

    switch ( requestpath ) {
            case "upload":
                form.parse( req );
                form.on( "field", function( field ){
   //throws "ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END" after 2nd request/upload trip
                    filestream( "index.html").pipe( resp );
                } )
                break;
            default:
                filestream( "index.html").pipe( resp );
                break;
        }
    } )
```

According to Node.js, stream piped to IncomingMessage will call end() after the readstream is closed. I am trying to understand what the cause of the error is. since formidable does not seem to end response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new `IncomingForm` instance for each request:

```
const { IncomingForm } = require('formidable');

...

switch (requestpath) {
  case "upload":
    const form = IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req);
    form.on("field", function(field) {
```

If you don't, for each request an additional `field` event will be emitted (I guess that `formidable` internally stores body data by appending to some internal buffer).

After the first `field` event is emitted, and your code streams the file (which subsequently ends the response), the second `field` event will try to do the same and will cause the error to occur.

Comment: Does formidable have access to the response object?

Comment: @NdifrekeEkim no, but I edited my answer to explain what is happening :D